# "Главное" — вводное слово или субстантивированное подлежащее?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, тире, подлежащее

**Главное, чтобы если не сразу, то в ближайшей перспективе ты мог занять должность, на которой будешь заниматься креативными задачами.**

Хочется поставить запятую, ибо пауза короткая, но вот союз "чтобы" не даёт. Можно посчитать "главное" односоставным назывным и поставить запятую?

Или считать "главное" субстантивированным сказуемым и ставить тире?

*Главное — [это] чтобы если не сразу, то в ближайшей перспективе ты мог занять должность, на которой будешь заниматься креативными задачами.*

Подобный пример у Пришвина:

*Самая поздняя осень – это когда от морозов рябина сморщится и станет, как говорят, «сладкой»* (в роли сказуемого выступает целое предложение).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Главное, чтобы если не сразу, то в ближайшей перспективе ты мог занять должность, на которой будешь заниматься креативными задачами.**

Предложения такой структуры встречаются часто, при этом обычно ставится **запятая, реже тире.**

**Примеры:**

А что нам ещё надо? **Главное, чтобы** всё кончалось хорошо.

**Самое главное, чтобы** подобное не повторилось и сейчас, на этот раз с землёй.

**Главное ― чтобы** человеку было что сказать, а помочь ему высказаться ― задача продюсера.

Смысл такой: ситуация, обозначенная предложением с союзом ЧТОБЫ, считается главной.

**1) Если поставить запятую,** то конструкцию можно рассматривать как СПП с придаточным изъяснительным и пропущенным указательным словом, например: Главное (то), чтобы подобное не повторилось и сейчас.

**2) Если поставить тире,** то конструкцию можно рассматривать как простое предложение, где главное ― подлежащее, выраженное субстантивированным прилагательным, а в позиции сказуемого находится не  слово/словосочетание, а предложение.